# Run Vb.net Program on Ubuntu Server

Tags: vb.net, ubuntu, nginx, mono, tcpclient

I have a very small vb.net program that has a message box and submit button! just for demonstration when for example send "Hi" it replies with "how are you" ( again, just for demonstration. If it were such as simple, I'd convert the code to PHP ). I want this program to listen on some port in my Ubuntu server that runs Nginx. and Instead of having an input box and a button It'd just accept incoming strings and send the reply string back to the client.

I tried creating the server program then Run it on my small Server using Mono. But this code ( server side ) wasn't working even on my computer:

```
    Dim msg As String
    Dim Data As String
    Do Until isListining = False
        If server.Pending = True Then
            Client = server.AcceptTcpClient
            Data = New StreamReader(Client.GetStream).ReadToEnd()
            msg = "" ' HERE I handle the Data and return the reply message
            Dim bytes() As Byte = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg)
            Client.GetStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
            Client.Client.Send(System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg))
            Client.Close()
        End If
        Thread.Sleep(100)
    Loop
```

- References ( creating the server ) :

[VB.NET Tutorial - Client / Server Network Programming - Simple Chat Application](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSiBbtxWpI8)

[A Peer-To-Peer LAN Chat Application in Visual Basic.Net using TcpClient and TcpListener](http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/11178/A-Peer-To-Peer-LAN-Chat-Application-in-Visual-Basic-Net-using-TcpClient-and-TcpListener.html)

This code has problem with sending back the respond to the client. I want to know if There's an easy way to directly run it on the server. and if not, then where's the problem on my code ? Thanks in advance.

NB: I found a lot of examples about running a local server but most of them also didn't work and add them in the references tab would be quite a list :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix my problem by converting my code to Python this way It can run on my Ubuntu Server. and then I've managed to run a [Simple HTTP Server](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BaseHttpServer) and then importing my code.

for more information if you were interested about the topic, please follow this thread : [REST API framework that works with my python program instead of Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32614751/rest-api-framwork-that-works-with-my-python-program-instead-of-database)