# REST API framework that works with my python program instead of Database

Tags: python, api, nginx, frameworks, eve

I wanted to create a very simple REST API. I found EVE Framework very promising and I want to instead of using a Database. import my .py code and execute it and return the string. It should be something like:

```
http://myipserver:5000/myprogram.py?string=xxx
```

where 'xxx' is the string I'm looking to get and then evaluate it using my .py code.

It'd be great if there's a way to make it work with EVE or any other Framework. I'm running Nginx.

NB: [my old question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32608095/run-vb-net-program-on-ubuntu-server), I understand that I should from Googling and Googling that I have to convert it to PHP or another programming language that runs on Linux so, I chose Python since I'm already familiar with it. and now I want to run it as REST API instead of just Socket/TCP simple server.

Comment: I'm not clear what the question is here. Why can't you use the Eve framework? Are you asking how to get nginx to communicate with a python application?

Comment: No, Eve designed to work with database. and It's really good at running a REST API. so I want the API it provides to run my python small program and return the output back in the response.

Comment: Every REST API framework can do the trick is what I'm looking for. not only EVE Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question right yes, you can mount custom endpoints on top of a Eve REST API. Not a long ago I wrote an [article](http://nicolaiarocci.com/building-custom-endpoint-handlers-with-eve/) about this, check it out for the details, but it really boils down to doing something like this:

```
from eve import Eve
app = Eve()

@app.route('/hello')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This is just leveraging the standard Flask features. Then you can access the `/hello` endpoint where your function will do whatever it needs to do.

Comment: Oh thanks for taking the time to answer me. and yeah. you got it right. Thanks for mention it. It was exactly what I was looking for. however. I found [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BaseHttpServer) And it's working just fine. But because I care so much about performance. I'm wandering which one would be faster. What I have already or using the EVE framework ?

Comment: Well for starters, if this is the right answer to your original question you might want to accept it, and eventually upvote :-) This will also help others in finding a solution to a similar issue. On which one to pick, it is your call of course. If you don't need Eve features, why use it in the first place? Maybe go with Flask alone however, rather than the base HTTP server. Will make things probably easier on you as your application grows.

Comment: Thanks for pointing Flask framework out seems very suits to my needs.

Comment: Hey man. So, I'm trying develop my program with EVE however I want to know if there's a way to get url string back like http://localhost:5000/home/that's-what-i-need ? thanks

Comment: Great article, Nicola. Just what I have been looking for. :-)